# What is the right way to compare non-learning based algorithms with learning-based algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation

Let's say that I apply an ML-based algorithm on a dataset, and using F-Score as the evaluation metric, obtain a score on the test set. Now, I have a non-learning based algorithm (say, a genetic algorithm) and I wish to compare it against the ML-based algorithm. What is the right way to do this? Using the same evaluation metric, do I just run the non-learning based algorithm only on the test set? Or should I run it on the entire dataset (train + test)? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Not sure if there is any distinction. If one could generate predictions with an algorithm, algorithm would have a capacity to learn. Model selection should apply i.e., using identical procedure to get generalised performance among competing models.

Comment: metrics does not depends on "how the response" is produced